# JQuery required multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there any way to make the selectors here required:

```
var $el = $('.top').children(':gt(2), :contains("word")');
```

According to [Multiple-Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), it will find the elements that match **any** of these two selectors.

How to find the elements that match **all** the selectors not **any** of them? `jQuery( "selector1, selector2, selectorN" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest to combine the selectors:

```
$('.a.b.c').css({'color':'blue'});
```

Another way would be to use a [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function with the *first selector* and add the *selector 2 to N* inside the `filter()` using the [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) function - see demo below:

```js
/*This combines the three selectors .a .b and .c*/
$('.a').filter(function(){
  return $(this).is('.b') && $(this).is('.c')
}).css({'color':'blue'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a">1</div>
<div class="b">2</div>
<div class="c">3</div>
<div class="a b">4</div>
<div class="a c">5</div>
<div class="b c">6</div>
<div class="a b c">7</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply connect the two selectors to eachother:

`var $el = $('.top').children(':gt(2):contains("word")');`